# In the specs2 framework, why does using a Scope prevent execution of a forAll quantifier?

Tags: scala, specs2, scalacheck

In the code below, how can I make Specs2 execute the first test?  The "print ones" test passes when it should fail.  The code inside the `forAll()` section is not executing because of the `new Scope`.

The `println` statements are only for tracing output.  Please let me know if you see any lines starting with "one".

The empty `Scope` is just for demonstrating the problem.  This is stripped-down from code where I actually use variables in a `Scope`.

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen
import org.scalacheck.Prop._
import org.specs2.ScalaCheck
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.Scope

class TestingSpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck {
  "sample test" should {
    "print ones" in new Scope { 
      println("The first test passes, but should fail")
      forAll(Gen.posNum[Int]) { (x: Int) =>
          println("one: " + x)
          (0 < x) mustNotEqual true
      } 
    } 

    "print twos" in { 
      println("The second test passes and prints twos")
      forAll(Gen.posNum[Int]) { (x: Int) =>
        println("two: " + x)
        (0 < x) mustEqual true
      } 
    } 
  }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
sbt> testOnly TestingSpec
The second test passes and prints twos
The first test passes, but should fail
two: 1
two: 2
two: 1
    ...
two: 50
two: 34
two: 41
[info] TestingSpec
[info] 
[info] sample test should
[info]   + print ones
[info]   + print twos
[info] 
[info] Total for specification TestingSpec
[info] Finished in 96 ms
[info] 2 examples, 101 expectations, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] 
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 28, 2015 3:14:15 PM
```

P.S. I updated my project dependency from version 2.4.15 to specs2 3.5.  Still has this issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because anything you put in a `Scope` must throw exceptions when there is a failure. A ScalaCheck `Prop` will not do anything unless you execute it so your example will always be passing.

The workaround is to transform the `Prop` into a specs2 `Result` by using the following implicit for example:

```
import org.specs2.execute._

implicit class RunProp(p: Prop) {
  def run: Result = 
    AsResult(p)
}
```

Then

```
"print ones" in new Scope { 
  println("The first test passes, but should fail")
   forAll(Gen.posNum[Int]) { (x: Int) =>
     println("one: " + x)
      (0 < x) mustNotEqual true
   }.run 
}
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  I appreciate your timely response.  Thank you for continuing to support a great testing library!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that I found is to start with `Prop` and then define your `Scope` as follow:

```
"print ones" in forAll(Gen.posNum[Int]) { (x: Int) =>
    new Scope { 
       println("The first test passes, but should fail")
       println("one: " + x)
        (0 < x) mustNotEqual true
    } 
}
```

Compared to @Eric's answer, I like this approach better because first you don't need and implicit class, second you don't have to call `run` which you might forget.